# Objective C: Protocol and Delegate syntax

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

is it possible to send back two parameters when calling a delegate method? I have a delegate I'm trying to set up to return two modified dates back to my parent but I get a syntax error for the second parameter. Is my syntax just wrong or is it not possible?

```
@protocol PeriodsChangedDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

-(void) periodsChanged: (NSDate *) newTimeStart, (NSDate *) newTimeFinished;

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
-(void) periodsChanged: (NSDate *) newTimeStart, (NSDate *) newTimeFinished;
```

write

```
-(void) periodsChanged: (NSDate *) newTimeStart  timeFinished:(NSDate *)newTimeFinished;
```

You dont pass two parameter by using `,` you separate them by `:`

Comment: Thanks.. this is what throws me a little with ObjC - I also need to specifiy parameter names.. so potentially does this mean that the delegate can be called with the parameters in any order as long as the parameter names are specified when called?

Comment: Objective-C methods almost never include "and" between parameters. `periodsChanged:timeFinished:` would be more idiomatic, although there's probably a better name for the first parameter too.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers yes you are correct, although a name is a name nothing more and nothing less, you could add it and you could not, it really depends on your personal style

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith Respectfully, I disagree. Coding conventions are very important when working alone or with others, to ensure consistency and predictability in a codebase. They're so valuable, in fact, that Apple publishes [coding guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) to make sure everyone is on the same page.

Comment: @SparkyNZ Parameters are named, but unfortunately cannot be reordered. The intention is for Objective-C messages to flow like a sentence; [for example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1001803-BCIDAIJE), `tableView:shouldSelectRow:`.

Comment: Thanks guys.. now I just need to figure out how to call the delegate with its multiple parameters..

Comment: @SparkyNZ do it like this [delegate periodsChanged:yourFirstDate timeFinished:yourSecondDate];

Comment: Thanks Omar - just about to add this:   if( [delegatePeriodsChanged respondsToSelector: @selector( periodsChanged: timeFinished: ) ] )
  {
    [delegatePeriodsChanged periodsChanged: timeStart timeFinished: timeFinish];
  }